# Error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'france'

Tags: sql

I am getting error . please suggeestt where i am wrong.
i am  giving formating

```
--Table
Alter TABLE [dbo].[store_2](enter code here
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [sub] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--

Alter TABLE [dbo].[store_1](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--Proc 

alter proc sele_2
(
@da nvarchar(100), @SR nVARCHAR(100) ,@sub nvarchar(50) 
) as begin

Declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)

Creat0e Table #ComplianceTem
( name varchar(100), email varchar(100)
)

set @SqlStr = N'Insert into #ComplianceTem (name,email)
select name,Email from '+@SR+'
union
select name,Email from store_2 s where 1=1 and s.sub= '+ CAST(@sub AS nVARCHAR(50))
print @sqlstr
execute sp_executesql @SQLstr  

select *from #ComplianceTem
end


exec sele_2 arvind,store_1, france
```

I am getting error . please help me where i am wrong

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Invalid column name 'france'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use parameters, you won't have this problem.  The problem is the lack of single quotes.  You can add them, but the right solution is:

```
set @SqlStr = N'Insert into #ComplianceTem (name,email)
select name, Email from '+@SR+'
union
select name, Email from store_2 s where 1=1 and s.sub = @sub
';

print @sqlstr
execute sp_executesql @SQLstr, N'@sub nvarchar(50)', @sub = @sub;
```

You cannot add the table name as a parameter, but you can add the value in the `where`.

EDIT:

If you are constructing the SQL string, then I would recommend the `replace()` approach:

```
set @SqlStr = N'Insert into #ComplianceTem (name,email)
select name, Email from @SR
union
select name, Email from store_2 s where 1=1 and s.sub = ''@sub''
';

set @SqlStr = replace(@SqlStr, '@SR', @SR);
set @SqlStr = replace(@SqlStr, '@sub', @sub);

. . .
```

Replacing values in strings with user inputs is discouraged because it opens the server to a SQL injection attack.  You can fix this by using `quotename` for the table name:

```
set @SqlStr = replace(@SqlStr, '@SR', quotename(@SR));
```

However, you don't want to do this for `@sub`, because it changes the meaning of the query.